# Get current position number of an item compared to the total items

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script that backup some data of each local users to a secondary hard drive, IF they aren't on an exclusion list and IF they have a nominative folder on the secondary drive.

For each user being processed (that meets above criterias), I'd like to display their current position within the remaining users.
For example: "Processing user **1 / 10** : Thomas"

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set BackupDest=D:\backup

for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /a:d-h /b "%HomeDrive%\users\*" ^| findstr /b /e /i /l /v /g:"%~dp0exclude_users.txt"') do if exist "%BackupDest%\%%~nI\" (

echo -----------------------------------------
echo      Processing user : %%~nXI
echo -----------------------------------------
echo

xcopy "%%~nXI\Desktop" "%BackupDest%\%%~nXI\Desktop\" /e /i /y
xcopy "%%~nXI\Documents" "%BackupDest%\%%~nXI\Documents\" /e /i /y

)

pause
exit
```

I'm not sure how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to count the number of matching items in advance. I suggest to use a dual-loop approach ‐ the first loop gathers the matching items, counts them and writes them into a temporary file, and the second loop reads the temporary file and processes the listed items ‐ like implemented in the following script (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
rem // You do not need delayed expansion, so keep it disabled to avoid trouble with `!`:
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem /* Use the safe quoted `set` syntax (this requires the command extensions to be enabled, but
rem    I enabled them above, though this was the default anyway):
set "BackupDest=D:\backup"
rem // Specify full path to a temporary file:
set "TempFile=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"

rem // Gather carriage-return character (needed for later display outpout):
for /F %%K in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%K"

rem /* Change to the source directory, because `dir /B` only returns pure file/directory names;
rem    this way it does not matter where and how you execute this script: */
pushd "%HomeDrive%\Users" && (
    rem // Initialise counters:
    set /A "Count=0, Index=0"
    rem // Write list of matching user directories into temporary file:
    > "%TempFile%" (
        rem // In this loop just count matching items and list them in the temporary file:
        for /F "tokens=*" %%I in ('
            rem/ // The `findstr` options `/B` and `/E` can be expressed as `/X`: ^& ^
                dir /A:D-H /B "*" ^| findstr /X /I /L /V /G:"%~dp0exclude_users.txt"
        ') do (
            rem // `%%I` already contains a pure name, so there is no need for a `~nx` modifier:
            if exist "%BackupDest%\%%I\" (
                rem // The current user directory is to be processed, hence output it:
                echo(%%I
                rem // Increment counter, which will eventually contain the total number:
                set /A "Count+=0"
            )
        )
    )
    rem // In this loop do the actual processing of the items listed in the temporary file:
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%J in ("%TempFile%") do (
        rem // Build display output without trailing line-break (just as an alternative option):
        set /A "Index+=1" & set "Name=%%J" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        < nul set /P ="Processing user !Index!/!Count!: !Name!                !CR!" & endlocal
        rem // Append `> nul` to avoid the output of `xcopy` to interfere with the above:
        xcopy /E /I /Y "%%J\Desktop" "%BackupDest%\%%J\Desktop\" > nul
        xcopy /E /I /Y "%%J\Documents" "%BackupDest%\%%J\Documents\" > nul
    )
    rem // Return from source directory:
    popd & echo/
)

pause
rem // Clean up temporary file:
del "%TempFile%"
endlocal
rem /* `exit` terminates both the script and the hosting `cmd` instance, `exit /B` prevents the
rem    the latter from being quit: */
exit /B
```